# A superharmonic function that is zero on a compact set 2

Tags: real-analysis, potential-theory

This question is related to this ([A superharmonic function that is zero on a compact set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4081112/a-superharmonic-function-that-is-zero-on-a-compact-set)) Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ with $m\geq 3$, and $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^m\setminus K$. Is there a continuous,  superharmonic function $u$ (or at least just superharmonic)  on $\mathbb{R}^m$ that vanishes on each point of $K$ and that tends to a positive number at infinity? The Green's function of $\Omega$ comes close, but it is subharmonic on a neighborhood of the boundary of $K$ and tends to zero at infinity.